# File group directory in file stream

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Sorry if my question is very basic , i am new to sql server.

I do not know what is the difference between `path` we enter in the file group directory and path we extract when we use `PathName()` function to return the path to binary file system.

[file group directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0pwM.jpg)

[path to binary file system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofzi7.jpg)

Comment: could you please explain with some examples on where you are seeing confusion

Comment: As i told i am new to sql server. I have started reading a book about how to work with Blobs. I would like to manage my pdf files in the server. before i was using ms access and made a link to files for opening them. Now i would like to use sql server instead of access. But now i do not know where files saved , in the book has been defined path one time we create data base with file stream storage and another time in create a table with file stream column, now i do not know what is the difference between these 2 path. I would like to send by image but app does not allow me.

Comment: can you show it by examples

Comment: i added 2 images from book. i would like to know what is diifference between path we enter in create a database with file stream storage and path in a table with a file stream storage or why the path we return from table is differnt with path we enter in the file group of database.